# Why is it that my Android app doesn't run when I remove a TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout

Well, it's basically a project a friend of mine started and I'm taking on what he left. If I remove this piece of code:

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="<redacted>"
        android:id="@+id/usernameTextView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

The app will open but will force quit whenever I switch to another Activity.

If that piece of code is there, the app runs smoothly.

What could it be?

Comment: The activity class connected to this layout file might be accessing this `TextView` using it's id. So, you need to remove that piece of code too.

Comment: Do you have the error's stacktrace that gets spit out when it force quits?

Comment: Provide log cat error description.

Comment: You have some piece of code that makes use of this TextView. Probably a `findViewById(R.id.usernameTextView)` inside the `onCreate` of your launcher activity

Answer (score 0):

Check any code in `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onDestroy()`, or generally in the place where you wrote the code of switching to another activity. Your `TextView` must have been called somewhere in your code, and now you removed it which will cause `NullPointerException` if it is being called anywhere in your activity.

You can also check your logcat to know what piece of code causes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You probably instantiating a *usernameTextView* `TextView` inside one of your activites. Go there, find and remove this line of code:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usernameTextView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your activity and remove the code relative to `findViewById(R.id.usernameTextView)`